# phpmailer not working in godaddy , nor in mail() working

Tags: smtp, phpmailer, sendmail

I am getting following error when trying to mail from godaddy smtp.

I am getting following errors 
Warning: require_once(class.phpmailer.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in filename on line 60

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'class.phpmailer.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php')

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['email']))
//if "email" is filled out, send email
  {
  //send email

 require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
//$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // 1 tells it to display SMTP errors and messages, 0 turns off all errors and messages, 2 prints messages only.
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "https";
$mail->Host = "smtpout.asia.secureserver.net";
$mail->Port = 25;

$mail->Username = "test@mydomain.com" ; // this is email on godaddy account
$mail->Password = "password";

$mail->From = "test@mydomain.com" ;
$mail->FromName = "some name" ;

$mail->AddAddress($_POST['email'], $name);
//$mail->AddReplyTo(“Email Address HERE”, “Name HERE”); // Adds a “Reply-to” address. Un-comment this to use it.
$mail->Subject = "site no. ".$_POST['site1']." ".$_POST['status']." for you " ;
$mail->Body = " Hi, your site  with no. ".$_POST['site1']." in phase ".$_POST['phase1']." has been ".$_POST['status']  ;

if ($mail->Send() == true) {
echo "The message has been sent";
}
else {
echo "The email message has NOT been sent for some reason. Please try again later";
echo "Mailer error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}


  }

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems the your PHP script is unable to locate the class.phpmailer.php file

- Try copying class.phpmailer.php file into the same directory as that of the PHP script

or

- Specify the full path to the class.phpmailer.php in the require_once

> If at all you don't happen to have the class.phpmailer.php file **:**

1. First download it from the PHPMailer website
2. Copy it to a location accessible by the script
3. Specify its path in the require_once